# How to use Forwards algorithm for HMM with Continuous Observation model $P(y|z_t=k)$

Tags: inference, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

I have implemented a Forwards-Backwards algorithm for discrete latents HMM given the observed distribution matrix $B$.

Now if the observed distribution matrix is a Gaussian instead of finite probabilities from Categorical distribution, how do I modify the Forwards-Backwards to infer the latents?

---

I know that $$
P(\mathbf z_t|y_t)=\text{normalize}(P(y_t|\mathbf z_t)\cdot[\mathbf A ^\top P(\mathbf z_t|y_{t-1})])
$$
where $\mathbf A$ is the discrete transition matrix.

When $P(y|z)$ is Categorical, I have no problem and is able to construct the matrix needed. Now if it is Gaussian, how do I use the algorithm above as defined in the standard Forwards algorithm?

I also recently implemented Kalman Filters but these are SSM where both the observation and latent distribution are continuous. In this HMM where the observation is a distribution, how do I perform inference?

I am thinking of discretizing the Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and std $\sigma$ into a finite large vector but it can't be possibly this right?

---

**Edit**
I think that I can simply substitute the Gaussian distribution as a matrix! for example:
$$
\lambda =\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)\\
\mathcal N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, the latent states are Normally distributed $P(\mathbf z_t|y_t)\sim \mathcal N(\boldsymbol \mu ,\mathbf\Sigma)$.

The inferred states are now simply the mean endowed with a Covariance matrix.